# Convert row data into column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I want to convert data as header of table, and header as rows how to convert?

here is the sample data please execute this SQL

```
DECLARE @MyData table( 
DateValue datetime,
Value1 int,
Value2 int,
Value3 int,
Value4 int,
ColumnData  Varchar(10)); 

INSERT INTO @MyData(DateValue,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,ColumnData)
VALUES('12/1/2016',10,20,30,40,'D1')

INSERT INTO @MyData(DateValue,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,ColumnData)
VALUES('12/1/2016',11,21,31,41,'D2')

INSERT INTO @MyData(DateValue,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,ColumnData)
VALUES('12/1/2016',12,22,32,42,'D3')

SELECT * FROM @MyData
```

---

```
+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|        DateValue        | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | ColumnData |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| 2016-12-01 00:00:00.000 |     10 |     20 |     30 |     40 | D1         |
| 2016-12-01 00:00:00.000 |     11 |     21 |     31 |     41 | D2         |
| 2016-12-01 00:00:00.000 |     12 |     22 |     32 |     42 | D3         |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
```

can it be possible to convert MyData into specific format(Refer image) in single query?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using pivot in sql server?

Answer (score 0):

If your columns and `columnData` are static you can pivot each value separately and then use `UNION ALL` to create a single table:

```
DECLARE @MyData table(DateValue datetime,   Value1 int, Value2 int, Value3 int, Value4 int, ColumnData  Varchar(10)); 
INSERT INTO @MyData(DateValue,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,ColumnData) VALUES('12/1/2016',10,20,30,40,'D1')
INSERT INTO @MyData(DateValue,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,ColumnData) VALUES('12/1/2016',11,21,31,41,'D2')
INSERT INTO @MyData(DateValue,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,ColumnData) VALUES('12/1/2016',12,22,32,42,'D3')

select 'Value1' as '12/1/2016',*, D1 + D2 + D3 as [Total] from(
        SELECT Value1, ColumnData FROM @MyData
    ) s
    pivot(
        sum(Value1) for ColumnData in (D1, D2 , D3)
    ) as pvt
union all
    select 'Value2' as '12/1/2016',*, D1 + D2 + D3 as [Total] from(
        SELECT Value2, ColumnData FROM @MyData
    ) s
    pivot(
        sum(Value2) for ColumnData in (D1, D2 , D3)
    ) as pvt
union all
    select 'Value3' as '12/1/2016',*, D1 + D2 + D3 as [Total] from(
        SELECT Value3, ColumnData FROM @MyData
    ) s
    pivot(
        sum(Value3) for ColumnData in (D1, D2 , D3)
    ) as pvt
union all
    select 'Value4' as '12/1/2016',*, D1 + D2 + D3 as [Total] from(
        SELECT Value4, ColumnData FROM @MyData
    ) s
    pivot(
        sum(Value4) for ColumnData in (D1, D2 , D3)
    ) as pvt
```

This is the output of this query:

[image]